# How do I use the same mp3 file more then once?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()

firsttime = False
song2switch = True

root = tk.Tk()
 
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=250)
canvas.pack()

def loadsong1():
    global song1
    song1 = tk.filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, initialdir="C:/",title="choose first song",filetypes=[("mp3 files", ".mp3")])
def loadsong2():
    global song2
    song2 = tk.filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, initialdir="C:/",title="choose second song",filetypes=[("mp3 files", ".mp3")])
def play():
    mixer.music.load(song1)
    mixer.music.play()
def switch():
    global firsttime
    global song2switch
    global time_of_song
    if firsttime == False:
        time_of_song = mixer.music.get_pos()
        time_of_song /= 1000
        mixer.music.stop()
        mixer.music.load(song2)
        mixer.music.play(start = time_of_song)
        firsttime = True
        song2switch = False
    else:
        if song2switch == False:
            time_of_song = mixer.music.get_pos()
            time_of_song /= 1000
            mixer.music.stop()
            mixer.music.load(song1)
            mixer.music.play(start = time_of_song)
            song2switch = True

playbutton = tk.Button(canvas,text="PLAY",command=play)
canvas.create_window(200,240,window=playbutton)
load1button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Load Song One",command=loadsong1)
canvas.create_window(100,240,window=load1button)
load2button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Load Song Two", command=loadsong2)
canvas.create_window(300,240,window=load2button)
switchbutton = tk.Button(canvas, text="SWITCH", command=switch)
canvas.create_window(200,200, window=switchbutton)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make this music player that can switch between two songs while keeping the same time between each other (for example, when I switch a song that has been playing for a minute, the other will start a minute in), but when i try to switch it to the first song, it makes this error:

> pygame.error: Couldn't read first 12 bytes of audio data

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have used `askopenfile(...)` which will open the selected file in read mode and return the *file handle*.

When you switch to `song2`, `song1` is closed.  When you want to switch back to `song1` again, `mixer.music.load(song1)` will fail with exception because the file is already closed.

Use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`.

Note 1: `mixer.music.get_pos()` returns the `elapsed` time relative to `start`, not the beginning.

Note 2: your switching logic will not work properly after switching two times.